# How to merge large sensor data with duplicate timestamp into a single average value data

Tags: java, shell, awk

I have a set of large sensor data sample with the same timestamp but different data which means there are numbers of data in the same timestamp. The data consist of timestamp, type of sensor and sensor data that look like this:

```
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081767,-0.5068207,9.878754   
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081890,-0.5068207,9.878344  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081787,-0.5035457,9.824754  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40084355,-0.4568207,9.878756  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081347,-0.5068277,9.823274  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40087856,-0.5068887,9.878758  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081787,-0.5068678,9.878344  
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,    0.40081897,-0.5045667,9.856754
```

My question is how to merge data of the same timestamp into an average value? It could be a very large amount of data so is there any scripts to do that?

Comment: We need more information.  How should the be data processed- by real time reads or from a log file? Does the data arrive in strict time order or out of order?  If you are writing your own Java application (not Javascript) why would you want this filtering in an external script, and what language(s) are you thinking of using?

Comment: When asking how to do something per-timestamp, only posting the data for 1 timestamp isn't useful. [edit]` your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output for at least 2 timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
$1 != prev { prt(); prev=$1 }
{
    ++cnt
    key = $1 OFS $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum[i] += $i
    }
}
END { prt() }
function prt(   i) {
    if (cnt) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sum[i]/cnt, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
    cnt = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2017-05-17 23:12:57 169,  TYPE_ACCELEROMETER,0.400828,-0.499895,9.86222
```

It's hard to say without more comprehensive sample input/output.